# Closing safari with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, safari

I want to open and then close a Safari tab on MacOS with a Python script, but I don't know what the command is... I wrote two lines to open the tab and now I need to know if the way to close an application in Windows also works on MacOS and if yes what the full application name of Safari is. I would really appreciate an answer.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('https://spotify.com', new=2)
```

That's what I wrote and now there would be

```
def closeApp():
    try:
        os.system('TASKKILL /F /IM safari.???')

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
```

Answer (score 2):

I personnaly use "webdriver" from "selenium" library I thinks that's easier.

Just import webdriver from selenium .

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Choose your browser

```
browser = webdriver.Safari()
```

Next open what you want

```
browser.get("https://spotify.com")
```

If you want to switch between tabs you can use

```
browser.swith_to_window(window_name)
```

Then when you're done just close the tab in use.

```
browser.close()
```